# Jquery dialog code throws error message undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am implementing a jquery dialog box containing some html code inside a jquery accordion. Some times the dialog pops up and sometimes I get an exception thrown saying "TypeError: undefined function". The html code is generated dynamically from php and consist of some clickable header files with the class name antennaCursor.

What's wrong with the code when I am receiving this error?

```
$( ".antennaCursor" ).live("click",function() {
  try {
    var data_id = $(this).attr("id");

    url = "http://192.168.0.10/wiki/GetInformation.php?data1"+data_id+"&type=somedata";

    dial=$("<div id='dialog2' style='text-align:left; width:auto; overflow:auto'></div>");
    dial.attr("title","Data information: " + $(this).attr("id"));
    dial.html('Fetching data! <img id="graph" src="/wiki/progress.gif" />');

    dial.dialog({ position: "left"});
    dial.dialog( "option", "width", 600 );
    $.get(url,{
       getmacroinfo : $(this).attr("id"), infotype : "draw"
    }, function(data){
    if ( $( "#accordion" ).data("ui-accordion") )  {      
       $( "#accordion").accordion("destroy");
       $( "#accordion").empty();
       $( "#accordion").remove();
    }
    dial.html(data);

    });
    dial.dialog( "open" );
    return false;
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

Edit:
The problem was not within the code. The error message came because jquery was not properly loaded.

Comment: Ok, which one is the undefined function?

Comment: It doesn't say which the undefined function is. The error message comes from the try-catch. The error message in the question is exactly the information I get in the alert.

Comment: Well remove the try-catch so that you'll get the line number.

Comment: It is complaining about row: dial.dialog({ position: "left"});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution to the problem.
I simply commented out the inclusion of the jquery files.

We are running a TWiki wiki page and the jquery is included in the code at a higher level. So there could be a conflict between the older jquery version and the latest that I tried to use.

Comment: I don't know why my original question was voted down. This is actually my last resort. I have been looking for the answer everywhere. Fortunatelly, I had some other code in which I used jquery dialog boxes, which made it possible for me to compare what could be so wrong.